# Backbone-RequireJs boilerplate for component based large web-projects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, boilerplate

We have a large web project, where we need components which can talk to each other which can be put in a central repository of components for different projects.
Using reuirejs and Backbone for the modular development. Went through different boilerplate available for backbone and requirejs, but none matched my requirement. So I have created following directory structure. It can be explained as follows.

```
---resources
 |---custom-components
   |---mycomponent
     |---js
       |---views
       |---models
       |---collections
     |---css
     |---templates
     |---mycomponent.js
   |---mycomponent2
     |---js
       |---views
       |---models
       |---collections
     |---css
     |---templates
     |---mycomponent2.js
 |---libraries
   |---backbone
   |---underscore
   |---jquery
   |---jquery-ui
 |---jqueryplugins
   |---jcarouselite
 |---thirdpartyplugins
 |---page-js
   |---mypage.js
   |---mypage2.js
```

1. resources directory will contain all the resources. Under that we will have 4 directories as mentioned.
2. libraries, jqueryplugins and thirdpartyplugins are obviusly the directories for the name they say.
3. page-js directory will contain the actual main-js which will be used inside our html file as requirejs data-main attribute.
4. Custom-component is where all widgets created by us will reside, as you can see it has a js file with same name as that of the component, which will be entry point of this widget. This directory also has directories for js, css and templates. CSS and templates will be loaded by text plugin and [CSS](https://github.com/VIISON/RequireCSS) plugin respectively. Js directory will contain all the backbone code to make this widget work.

Custom components will be asked by main-js residing in page-js.

Coming to what I need.
    1. I want experts to have review this directory structure in perspective of large web projects, where you will need to share your widgets with other teams. suggestions are welcome.
    2. My each custom-component will define a module, which will have dependencies within package structure as well as outside package structure. I want to know, if there is any way to use r.js to optimize only my custom widget dependency within package structure and let the plugins and libraries optimized separately.
    3. I am developing single page ajax application, so I will be asking modules on demand so I need to cleanup modules and widgets when I dont need them, is there any way for cleaning up I should be aware of?

Comment: have you checked `backbone-aura` (http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-aura/) by addy osmani, based on the documentation and your requirements it might help you generate the required architecture

Comment: I did stumble upon this couple of days ago before asking this question, but didn't found the link you specified.Thanks for the link. I looked into that and it does solve one of my problem , cleaning up. It also add one more exciting feature of pub/sub architecture. But my query 2 remains still there, is there a way to optimize my widget only.

Comment: can's you just use the `exclude` option to avoid optimize for external  or unwanted dependencies

Comment: by optimize separately, you mean you would like to use the already minified libraries provided by vender (jquery.min) instead of minify it locally??

Comment: Frankly speaking I have not tried r.js directly but only reading about the same. Reading at http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs I assume that r.js can optimize only javascript dependencies which are used directly by your html in data-main attribute. Rather than that, I'll like to optimize only a custom-component, as in my example provided above, I will like to optimize module defined in mycomponent.js using define() syntax which has internal dependencies in --js directory, to be optimized to only one file.So at deployement I'll not have to make multiple file hits for same cmpnent

Comment: this config file might help you understand the options available https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Answer (score 2):

***About the directory structure***

As a directory structure pattern, I highly recommend using directory structure of cakePHP. it's really robust as in words!! I'm running multiple apps (one of them is as big as Groupon) and it works just like a charm.
You may need to tweak it a little because, you know, cake is a PHP framework and yours is a javascript one.

Here is the cake's awesome MVC directory structure:

[image]

Please note that you may host thousands of apps on a single cake installation. so if you're interested, what are you waiting for? [go to their site](http://cakephp.org/) and read their docs.

---

***About the cleaning up techniques***

Well, here is one of the downsides of the Javascript which I don't like. there is no real way to destroy a OO module like in Java or C++. here we don't have such things like C++'s `~` destructors.

For many years, programmers use `module = null` to free up memory from un-used codes.

Take a look at these also:

- [Can dynamically loaded JavaScript be unloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346897/can-dynamically-loaded-javascript-be-unloaded)
- [Loading/unloading Javascript dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693395/loading-unloading-javascript-dynamically)
- [How to unload a javascript from an html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365062/how-to-unload-a-javascript-from-an-html)

Hope it helps and good luck on designing your app ;D

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'm late in answering this, but anyway let me share my views here, incase someone else finds it useful.

1. Your directory structure looks alright. It is always a better design to keep your business components self contained in to a particular directory. I will not recommend Cake MVC structure which break the Open Close Principle. Also have a look at the directory structure recommended by http://boilerplatejs.org which is a reference architecture for large scale JavaScript development.
2. I do not get the question very clear. when r.js is run it will optimize all JS files it find in the directory (exclude possible) and then create a single script by going though the dependency tree. In production you only need that single script (plus locale files if i18n plugin is used)
3. Read my blog post below. It might give you some hints: http://blog.hasith.net/2012/11/how-much-multi-page-single-page.html